# pgfplots: How to make a legend entry span and centered in an entire row of the legend matrix?

Tags: pgfplots, legend

How to make the legend entry of `x` span and centered in the entire first row while continuing printing the rest of entries in the subsequent rows and columns?

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={
    at={([yshift=30pt]0.5,1)},anchor=north,
    text width=1in,
    cells={align=left},
    minimum height=2mm
},
legend columns=2,
xmin=0, xmax=10,
ymin=0, ymax=10,
]
\addplot [red,      line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {x};
\addlegendentry{$x$}
%
\addplot [black,    line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {(x-5)^2};
\addlegendentry{$(x-5)^2$}
%
\addplot [yellow,   line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {10-(x-5)^2}; \addlegendentry{$10-(x-5)^2$}
%
\addplot [orange,   line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {10-x};
\addlegendentry{$10-x$}
%
\addplot [green,   line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {5};
\addlegendentry{5}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\label` and `\ref` one can pull individual legend entries (image only) and construct you own legend using a tabular.  This is basically what pgfplots does, only one can add `\multicolumn` this way.

Note, I did not try to reproduce your positioning, assuming that you really didn't want it to overlap your plots.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=border,
xmin=0, xmax=10,
ymin=0, ymax=10,
]
\addplot [red,      line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {x};
\label{legend1}
%
\addplot [black,    line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {(x-5)^2};
\label{legend2}
%
\addplot [yellow,   line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {10-(x-5)^2};
\label{legend3}
%
\addplot [orange,   line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {10-x};
\label{legend4}
%
\addplot [green,   line width = 5pt,   domain=0:10]    {5};
\label{legend5}
\end{axis}
\node[draw,above=2pt] at (border.north) {\begin{tabular}{ll}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\ref{legend1} $x$} \\
\ref{legend2} $(x-5)^2$ & \ref{legend3} $10-(x-5)^2$ \\
\ref{legend4} $10-x$ & \ref{legend5} 5
\end{tabular}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]